# Multiply rows in 2 columns by grouping flagged rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, logic

I have a dataframe DF, which has the following data; around 300000 rows

```
<DF
A B C
1 2 0
2 5 0
4 5 2
4 7 0
7 8 0
9 7 -2
2 5 0
4 7 0
5 1 2
4 7 0
7 8 0
9 7 -2
2 5 0
4 7 0
5 1 2
```

I want to perform a mathematical operation on the data set with the following logic

> Select all rows till first occurrence of 2 in C(ignoring -2 in the middle)
>
> Compute avg of all these of (A*B) and add it column D (Implying all these rows in column D will have the same value)
>
> Select all rows from first occurrence of 2 till the second occurrence
>
> Compute avg of (A*B) for these rows and add it column D
>
> ... Do the same till
>
> Select all rows from last occurrence of 2 till the second  last occurrence
>
> Compute avg of (A*B) for these rows and add it column D

The result should look like

```
<Result
A B C D
1 2 0 6
2 5 0 6
4 5 2 34.16667
4 7 0 34.16667
7 8 0 34.16667
9 7 -2 34.16667
2 5 0 34.16667
4 7 0 34.16667
5 1 2 27.85714
4 7 0 27.85714
7 8 0 27.85714
9 7 -2 27.85714
2 5 0 27.85714
4 7 0 27.85714
5 1 2 NA
```

How to implement this logic in R? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Always, try including a reproducible example ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DF)`), grouped by the cumulative sum of logical vector (`C==2`), we get the `mean` of `A * B` and multiply with the the values generated by `NA^(.N==1)` (`.N==1` returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE for number of rows that are equal to 1 or not and using `NA^` converts this to NA/1) so that all groups that have only one element returns NA and others have the `mean(A*B)`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,  D := NA^(.N==1)*mean(A*B) , .(grp = cumsum(C==2))]
DF
#    A B  C        D
# 1: 1 2  0  6.00000
# 2: 2 5  0  6.00000
# 3: 4 5  2 34.16667
# 4: 4 7  0 34.16667
# 5: 7 8  0 34.16667
# 6: 9 7 -2 34.16667
# 7: 2 5  0 34.16667
# 8: 4 7  0 34.16667
# 9: 5 1  2 31.66667
#10: 4 7  0 31.66667
#11: 7 8  0 31.66667
#12: 9 7 -2 31.66667
#13: 2 5  0 31.66667
#14: 4 7  0 31.66667
#15: 5 1  2       NA
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks @akrun, this was flawless!

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(ind = cumsum(C == 2)) %>% 
        group_by(ind) %>% 
        mutate(D = mean(A*B), D = replace(D, n() == 1, NA))
```

Comment: Also, how do I add the D column I get here to the original dataframe?

Comment: It worked like a breeze! Thanks for saving my day @Satos

Comment: When I tried it again, I get an Error: cannot modify grouping variable.

Comment: weird...are you including `ind` variable anywhere else?

Comment: No. rm(ind) too gives a warning, that object 'ind' not found

Comment: Tried the rm(ind) and running the code, a couple of times. I still get the same error

Comment: Does it work If you run it on the example data you posted on your question? Also what version of `dplyr` are you using?

Comment: No, its not running on the example data. I am using dplyr_0.5.0